# Shared connection from a wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection-sharing

Can I share a connection using my laptop, which is the source of the connection is coming from wireless connection, because I ever share the connection with the USB Modem and successful (can share) but if the source comes from the wireless connection it is failures.
is it possible ?, if so
what is the solution ?

here i am using windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to create a network bridge inside Windows 7. See the Microsoft article on [how to create a network bridge](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Create-a-network-bridge) in Windows 7.

Depending on how you will be connecting the other computer to which you want to share your connection, you will need either a second wireless network card, or a *wired* network card. Chances are that the computer that's gonna be sharing the connection already has a wired network card. But for a wireless connection from the second computer you will need a wireless network card in the form of a Wifi adapter.

For a complete wireless set-up you will need:

- Two computers (obviously)!
- Three wireless network cards or adapters!
- A wireless router!
- Internet connection! (Obviously, unless you just want to do simple
  file sharing between the two computers.)

Answer (score 0):

On `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections` open the properties of your wireless connection, on Sharing tab, enable the connection sharing and select the connection in which you want to share to. However, do remember most wireless adapter can only connect to one wireless network at once, so you can't share the internet to other via wifi (unless you got another wifi adapter, an external USB type, perhaps?), which left the only sharing options via cable.